# Setting mock property via Setup causes 'Expression is not a method invocation'

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I have the below code where my Mock interface has a Recorder property which is a class.

I then try to set a property on that class but I get a `Expression is not a method invocation` error. Could you help?

The error is at runtime when it goes to try an set the enum property. It throws an ArgumentException with the below stack trace:

```
at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.ToMethodCall(LambdaExpression expression)
   at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass1c`2.<Setup>b__1b()
   at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)
   at Moq.Mock.Setup[T,TResult](Mock mock, Expression`1 expression, Func`1 condition)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
```

Thanks

```
//Works
var mock = new Moq.Mock<IEngine>(); 
//Works
mock.Setup(x => x.Recorder).Returns(new Moq.Mock<Recorder>().Object);  
//Fails on the next line assigning a property value!!!
mock.Setup(x => x.Recorder.RunState).Returns(Recorder.eRunStates.Play);
```

**UPDATE -** I have found that RunState is not a property but a field/member which is a enum

Comment: Could you tell us *where* you get the error? Is it a compile-time error or an execution time error, and if it's an execution time error, when does it occur?

Comment: So which call is failing - the first or the second? (If it's the first, let's remove the second one from the picture entirely...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that creating a mock of Recorder and then assigning values to the mock object seems to fix the issue. Not sure if that is the correct way to do things though.

```
var mockRecorder = new Moq.Mock<Recorder>();
mockRecorder.Object.RunState = Recorder.eRunStates.Play;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should be returning the mock you've created in the first part for the second part:

```
var mockRecorder = new Moq.Mock<Recorder>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Recorder).Returns(mockRecorder.Object);
mockRecorder.Setup(x => x.RunState).Returns(Recorder.eRunStates.Play);
```

That's just a guess, without having used Moq myself - but it makes sense.

However, this looks like it's going to end up being fairly fragile. You might want to consider using a fake instead here - for at least *one* of the objects, if not both.

EDIT: Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart), an alternative would be:

```
// Moq will set up the hierarchy for you...
mock.Setup(x => x.Recorder.RunState).Returns(Recorder.eRunStates.Play);
```

Comment: That causes the same error unfortunately. By fake do you mean a handwritten one?

Comment: @Jon: Yes. It feels pretty brittle to rely on specific properties being called.

Comment: This is nasty legacy code and I'm on the verge of giving up to be honest

Comment: @Jon: You still haven't given us much information about *where* this error is occurring... can you come up with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you use SetupGet on the mocks rather than setup this will work

```
var mockRecorder = new Moq.Mock<Recorder>();
mock.SetupGet(x => x.Recorder).Returns(mockRecorder.Object);
mockRecorder.SetupGet(x => x.RunState).Returns(Recorder.eRunStates.Play);
```

Comment: Same problem. Have noticed that its a field not a property

Comment: Yes because I need to assert that a method in IEngine is called but this needs to be mocked and passed to another class

Comment: Not sure fields can be mocked. Can you subclass Recorder and pass that in?

Comment: I've added an answer and set the fields directly on the mock object although not sure that's entirely correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the setup on your Mock object to configure the RunState property instead.

```
var mockRecorder = new Mock<Recorder>();
mockRecorder.Setup(x => x.RunState).Returns(eRunStates.Play);

mock.Setup(x => x.Recorder).Returns(mockRecorder.Object);
```

EDIT: FYI, you need to do all the setup on the mock before accessing the .Object property as the object is created at this point and further setups cannot happen.

Also, a couple of suggestions, it looks like your enum for run states is nested in your recorder class, I'd move it into a separate class & additionally drop the 'e' prefix.